# get each line of a command in an array bash raspbian

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, ssl, raspbian

I'm trying to improve my scripting skills.
I know there's online converters that are doing it but i'd like to make a script that compare in a certain folder (`/opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/`), if the .crt are already in the .pem format and if not convert them.

So i know this clearly isn't the best way to do so... But i've started like this:

`

```
#!/bin/bash
#remove both files if they already exists
rm crt.txt
rm pem.txt 
#certificate selection in .crt format
Certificate_crt=$(sudo ls /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/ | grep .crt | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/')

#certificate selection in .pem format
Certificate_pem=$(sudo ls /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/ | grep .pem | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/') 

#sending results in text files
echo "$Certificate_crt" >> crt.txt
echo "$Certificate_pem" >> pem.txt

#recovery of certificate names in .crt not having a .pem equivalent
Certificate_crt_WO_pem=$(cat crt.txt | grep -v "$Certificate_pem" | tr " " "\n")
#echo "$Certificate_crt_WO_pem"


#initialisation 

i=0

#Print the split string

for i in "${Certificate_crt_WO_pem[@]}"
do
    name_certificate=$(echo $i | tr " " "\n")  
    echo "${name_certificate[@]}"  
    echo "$i"
    i=i+1   
done
```

`

The thing is that when my "for" is launched, it stores all the result of "Certificate_crt_WO_pem" in the array $name_certificate[0] and then stop it self.

What i want is to store, line by line, the result of "`cat crt.txt | grep -v "$Certificate_pem" | tr " " "\n"`" into the array name_certificate.

This array will be use to launch something like this " `openssl -in $name_certificate[$i].crt -out $name_certificate[$i].pem PEM`" (in a for loop in the will to convert every namefile.crt in every namefile.pem).

If someone can help me i'll be more than gratefull... (And yes i've already tried to search on the net, had followed some online courses but none of them was saying the same thing about the bash's arrays, so i'm a bit lost...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What i want is to store, line by line, the result of

Then do that.

```
var=$(something)
#   ^^ - normal variable assignment

var=(      $(something)      )
#  ^^                        ^ - array assignment
# the unquoted result of expansions is split on IFS
#    default on tabs, newlines and spaces
```

so I guess you want:

```
Certificate_crt_WO_pem=($(grep -v "$Certificate_pem" crt.txt))
```

Doing `cat file | grep` is a [useless use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html). Use `grep .. file` or `< file grep ...`.

Remember [do not parse `ls` output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead). Don't `ls | something`. Prefer globulation or `find` instead.

Read [how to read a stream line by line in bashfaq](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). Read [how to use arrays in bashfaq](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005).

Note that `grep` parses a regex, so `grep .pem` matches *any character* followed by `pem`. I guess you wanted `grep '\.pem'`. I do not think `grep -v "$Certificate_pem"`  does what you think it does - I guess you meant to use `comm` or `join` to filter elements from one newline separated separated that are present in the other list.

> This array will be use to launch something like this " openssl -in $name_certificate[$i].crt -out $name_certificate[$i].pem PEM"

The best would be not do it, rather parse the data as they come, not store them in variables.

```
# get all .crt fiels
find /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -name '*.crt' |
# remove extension
sed 's/\.crt$//' |
# filter out files where .pem does exists already
while IFS= read -r file; do
    if [[ -r "$file".pem ]]; then continue; fi
    printf "%s\n" "$file"
done |
# execute openssl for the rest
xargs -d'\n' -i{} openssl -in {}.crt -out {}.pem PEM
```

but if you want, rather use `mapfile` to store a string with a newline separated list into an array (be sure to understand [how to store variables in a pipeline](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)).

```
mapfile -t Certificate_crt_WO_pem < <(something)
```

Comment: ok i see what you've done here.
I've learned to store my results into variables but it is indeed better if i don't do that.

I just don't understand the double [ ] utility in your. "if".
But it is not working... i got an error:
certificate.sh: ligne 7: syntax error near the unexpected symbol "done".
certificate.sh: ligne 7: `    if [[ -r "$file".pem ]]; then continue; done'

But if i correctly understood, it is exactly what i want to do so thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: `then continue; done` -> `then continue; fi` a typo. The `[[` is a bash builtin that is mean to be improved `[`/`test` command  with special handling, see [bash manual conditional constructs [[ expression ]]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b)

Comment: Oh right ! i didn't saw it... 
Ok i understand. There's still an error for the openssl command, i've tried to add x509 between "openssl" and "-in" but it is not what cause the error.
I get:  
Invalid command '-in'; type "help" for a list.

and:
"x509: Unknown parameter PEM
x509: Use -help for summary."
if i add x509

Comment: Well, then maybe remove the `PEM` on the end.